# WindowsXP won't start on my COMPAQ Presario - restarting help

Tags: windows-xp, reboot

Help my windows xp is dying all of a sudden. When I start it in normal mode - I get as far as the windows loading screen. Then for a split microsecond teh blue screen of death shows up and the system restarts. I tried to restart in safe mode but when loading drivers it gets stuck on mup.sys and doesn't proceed beyond it.

I cant find my recovery disks and don't know what to do - there is a recovery drive but how can I fix my pc. I don't want to reformat it at all. Cant afford that!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is unlikely to be with mup.sys - this is one of the last drivers loaded and it gets the blame (along with USB drivers) as it is sometimes the last one displayed even if the problem is with something else.

Try doing the option `Disable restart on system failure` and then copy down what the blue screen error message is.

As a technician, if this came in to me and I was told/saw what you have said, my first thought would be that either there is faulty memory (run [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org)) or a faulty hard drive (check for weird noises, and try a scan from [HDAT2](http://www.hdat2.com/))

At a last resort, if it isn't faulty hardware, I would unplug the drive or use a Linux live CD that has hard drive access and attempt to copy all your data off followed by a reinstall from the recovery media.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do I set the option to not restart on system failure

Comment: Press F8 and it should be on the menu you use to choose safe mode.

Comment: no it isnt :( what do i do